# How do I set the last modified date of a file in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I only find a predicate time_file/2 to access the 
last modified date of a file.

> **time_file(+File, -Time)**
>   Unify the last modification time of File with Time.
>   http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=time_file/2

How could I explicitly set the last modified date 
of an existing file to some time value?

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see.
There is an additional package called library(filesex)
with the title "Extended operations on files".

There I find:

> **set_time_file(+File, -OldTimes, +NewTimes)**
>   Query and set POSIX time attributes of a file.
>   http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=set_time_file/3

Ok, Problem solved.